# Get the column number per row containing specific character in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a data frame like below.

```
a <- c('A', 'b', 'c')
b <- c('b', 'c', 'A')
c <- c('c', 'A', 'b')
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

df
  a b c
1 A b c
2 b c A
3 c A b
```

I want to generate additional columns like below. Basically, df$b_pos is specifying whether the 'b' is positioned either before or after the 'A' (the same principle applies to df$c_pos).

```
df$b_pos <- c('after A', 'before A', 'after A')
df$c_pos <- c('after A', 'before A', 'before A')

df
  a b c    b_pos    c_pos
1 A b c  after A  after A
2 b c A before A before A
3 c A b  after A before A
```

I want to write lines like below so that I can automate the process.

```
df$b_pos <- ifelse(get_the_column_index_of_A > 
                     get_the_column_index_of_b, 'before A', 'after A')
df$c_pos <- ifelse(get_the_column_index_of_A > 
                     get_the_column_index_of_c, 'before A', 'after A')
```

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could give me a tip what to put instead of 'get_the_column_index_of_A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that "A" occurs exactly once in each row, then you can get a vector of column indices like this:

```
> apply(df=="A",1,which)
[1] 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with`max.col`

```
df[c('b_pos', 'c_pos')] <- lapply(letters[2:3], function(x) 
         c("before A", "after A")[1+(max.col(df=="A", "first") < max.col(df==x, "first"))])
df
#  a b c    b_pos    c_pos
#1 A b c  after A  after A
#2 b c A before A before A
#3 c A b  after A before A
```

---

Or another option would be `paste`ing the dataset by row and check the patterns with `grepl`

```
df[c('b_pos', 'c_pos')] <- lapply(c("A.*b",  "A.*c"), function(x) 
           c("before A", "after A")[grepl(x, do.call(paste0, df))+1L])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `ifelse` and `grep`,

```
df$b_pos <- ifelse(apply(df, 1, function(i) grep('A', i)) > 
                          apply(df, 1, function(i) grep('b', i)), 'before A', 'after A')

df$c_pos <- ifelse(apply(df[,1:3], 1, function(i) grep('A', i)) > 
                     apply(df[,1:3], 1, function(i) grep('c', i)), 'before A', 'after A')
df
#  a b c    b_pos    c_pos
#1 A b c  after A  after A
#2 b c A before A before A
#3 c A b  after A before A
```